# not getting array exact value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

my orginal output is

below

```
[status] => 1
[schedule_status] => 1
[cid] =>3
[cdate] => 16-10-18 01:10:52
[did] => 16
[jid] => 4
```

After i use seperate array value using

```
$count = count($_POST[user]);

if($count>=1) { 

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {

        $candi_id =array('cid'=>$_POST[user][cid][$i]);

        $scheduleUp = array('cid'=>$_POST[user][cid][$i],'jid'=>$_POST[data][jid][$i],'did'=>$_POST[data][did][$i]);
    }
}
```

iam getting did is 1 why?

Answer (score 1):

You have single dimensional array. So why you try to fetch the data as loop? do not use `$_POST[data][did][$i]` please use as `$_POST[data][did]`

What it will do is:
`$_POST[data][did]` is return the result of `16` now from the string you are trying to access as array and fetch record for `[$i]` and starting of `$i` is `0` so it will return the 1st character from the string. If it is of `1` then it will return `6`.

So please try to remove `[$i]` from the end.